# Problem with executing Python code in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

I've done everything to setup Python in Sublime Text 3.

When I execute my code, it displays the 1st line and then nothing else.

I can type after the 1st line but nothing happens.

This happens on every code I execute but i will provide my code and explain what it does

(code is on Croatian so dont mind the text)

Python version: 3.9.2

The code:

```
print('\n')

height = int(input("Unesi svoju visinu: "))

width = int(input("Unesi svoju debljinu: "))

BMI = width / (he/100)**2


if BMI<=18.4:
    print("Ti se moraš udebljati!")

elif BMI<=24.9:
    print("Dobar si!")

elif BMI<=29.9:
    print("Malo se trebaš smršaviti!")

elif BMI<=34.9:
    print("Trebaš se smršaviti!")

elif BMI<=39.9:
    print("Trebaš se puno smršaviti!")

else:
    print("Moraš odmah na treniranje!")
```

What the code does:  It goes through the first input, when I type in the console to enter the input and I press enter, the code just stops executing.

VIDEO OF PROBLEM: https://youtu.be/ETsFJjw8O7s

Comment: Yes it does, i anwsered my own question down below

Comment: I know. But you practically re-iterated what the answer there says and then linked to it. That doesn't justify another answer. You can simply mark the question as a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search leads you to [this](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/python-3-input-doesnt-work/34418/2)
discussion on the Sublime forum from 2018.

> Sublime Text does not support inputting data into a program. You can up vote this feature request on: Currently you can try to install the package https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL and use it to run you program from a Sublime Text view. You you can try out the VSCode editor: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode, which is pretty similar with Sublime Text.

I also cannot get user input to work, so presumably Sublime Text still does not support user input.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback